# Get all implementors of an interface in dbus?

Tags: python, dbus

I'm writing a script to get the currently playing track for whatever media player is currently playing. Both of the players I'm interested in implement the `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player` interface:

[image]

I'd like to be able to get a list of all implementors of this interface so I can display the album info of the currently playing song in either Banshee or Nuvola Player depending on what's playing.

Here's my current code:

```
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

player = bus.get_object('org.bansheeproject.Banshee', '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
properties = dbus.Interface(player, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')

metadata = properties.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Metadata')
```

How can I convert this into something which would pull up everything implementing `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter over registred names:

```
filter(lambda x: x[:22] =='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2', bus.list_names())
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate more?